# How to avoid same instance variables for footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a footer in my rails application that shows all recent posts and categories produced by two instances variables in the welcome_controller.rb

But then if i go to another section that has a different controller responsible i get an error as the @posts and @categories instance variables are not there to loop through and list the latest posts and categories.

welcome_controller.rb (code extract)

```
@categories = Category.all
@posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
```

_footer.html

```
<div class="row footer-black">
    <div class="large-3 columns text-left">
      <h4>Categories</h4>
      <ul>
        <% @categories.each do |c| %>
          <% unless c.header? %>
            <% if c.restriction %>
              <% if check_for_free_questions_in_restricted_category(c) %>
                <li> <%= link_to c.title, category_random_free_question_path(c),'data-no-turbolink' => true %> </li>
              <% else %>
                <li> <%= link_to c.title, new_subscription_path,'data-no-turbolink' => true %> </li>
              <% end %>
            <% else %>
              <li> <%= link_to c.title, category_random_question_path(c),'data-no-turbolink' => true %> </li>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-5 columns text-left">
      <h4>Latest Posts</h4>
      <ul>
        <% @posts.each do |p| %>
          <li> <%= link_to truncate(p.title, length:70), blog_post_path(p) %> </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns text-left social-links">
      <h4>Social</h4>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

is there a way to show categories and posts in footer without instantiating same variables over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'. Every variable **must** be instantiated (initialized) before it can be used (in this case, in your view).

Now, there are some more efficient ways of instantiating these variables than writing:

```
@categories = Category.all
@posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
```

in multiple controllers. But, that's a different question. If you're interested in that, then ask a new question or refine this one.